# Enable Checkbox based on Radio Button Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, radio-button

I have Group of Checkbox , inside Treeview (bootstrap)
I'm Trying to create from each in the top Radio Button , Show and Hide function for specif Checkbox

Everything I've tried so far has failed.

I have 5 Radio button :
 -

1. Radio button 1 show all checkbox with id matching FCB & FCTK - HIDE
   THE REST
2. Radio button 2 show only all check boxes with id matching FCB - HIDE THE REST
3. Radio Button 3 show only all check boxes with id matching FCTK- HIDE THE REST
4. Radio button 4 show All Check boxes
5. Radio button 5 i will add new checkbox that he can show ALL options
   and the new added check boxes

> any idea how to correctly do this?
>
> I have an a idea but i failed when i tried to do it:
>
> I thought of doing an array with each Checkbox ID, and then search document elements and create foreach loop, Is that possible?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->

        <title>" TZ Generator</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="ConstructorMain.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>

                <!-- Form Name -->
                <!-- <legend>Documents Generator</legend>-->

                <nav class="navbar navbar-default no-margin">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                            <div class="navbar-header fixed-brand">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"  id="menu-toggle">
                                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-rocket fa-4"></i> " OTSP Team</a>
                            </div><!-- navbar-header-->
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                            <li class="active" ><button class="navbar-toggle collapse in" data-toggle="collapse" id="menu-toggle-2"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></li>
                                        </ul>
                            </div><!-- bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 -->
                </nav>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="filename">Company Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="filename" name="filename" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">
                        <span class="help-block">File name for the generated file</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Certified Or Non -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="type">Product Type</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label for="type-0">
                                <input type="radio" name="type" id="type-0" onchange="checkcert();" value="cert"> Certified " Products
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label for="type-3">
                                <input type="radio" name="type" id="type-3" onchange="checkcertFCB();" value="certFCB"> Certified " Products By FCB
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label for="type-4">
                                <input type="radio" name="type" id="type-4" onchange="checkcertFCTK();" value="certFCTK"> Certified " Products By FCTK
                            </label>
                        </div>                  
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label for="type-1">
                                <input type="radio" name="type" id="type-1" onchange="checkcertNON();" value="non"> Non-Certified " Product
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label for="type-2">
                                <input type="radio" name="type" id="type-2" onchange="checkcertUNI();" value="full"> Universal
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- AV & CC -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="avcc[]">Protection Type</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label for="avcc-0">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="avcc-0" id="avcc-0[]" value="AV.docx"> Anti-virus
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label for="avcc-1">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="avcc-1" id="avcc-1[]" value="CC.docx"> Control Center
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Product Line Tree New  -->
                <br></br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ostype">Operating System Platform</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div id="selection">
                            <ul>        <!-- DSS -->
                                <li>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="DSS" id="DSS-0[]" value="DSS-TXT.docx">
                                    <label for="DSS">DSS :</label>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="DSS-1-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="DSS-1" id="DSS-1[]" value="DSS-WIN.docx">
                                            <label for="DSS-1">Windows</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="DSS-3-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="DSS-3" id="DSS-3[]" value="DSS-WIN-CERT-FCB.docx">
                                            <label for="DSS-3">Windows CERT-FCB</label>
                                        </li>           
                                        <li id="DSS-4-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="DSS-4" id="DSS-4[]" value="DSS-WIN-CERT-FCTK.docx">
                                            <label for="DSS-4">Windows CERT-FCTK</label>
                                        </li>                                   
                                        <li id="DSS-2-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="DSS-2" id="DSS-2[]" value="DSS-LINUX.docx">
                                            <label for="DSS-2">Linux</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="DSS-5-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="DSS-5" id="DSS-5[]" value="DSS-LINUX-CERT-FCB.docx">
                                            <label for="DSS-5">Linux CERT-FCB</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="DSS-6-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="DSS-6" id="DSS-6[]" value="DSS-LINUX-CERT-FCTK.docx">
                                            <label for="DSS-6">Linux CERT-FCTK</label>
                                        </li>                                   
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <br></br>
                                <li>    <!-- SSS -->
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="SSS" id="SSS-0[]" value="SSS-TEXT.docx">
                                    <label for="SSS">SSS :</label>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="SSS-1-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="SSS-1" id="SSS-1[]" value="SSS-WIN.docx">
                                            <label for="SSS-1">Windows</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="SSS-3-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="SSS-3" id="SSS-3[]" value="SSS-WIN-CERT-FCB.docx">
                                            <label for="SSS-3">Windows CERT-FCB</label>
                                        </li>               
                                        <li id="SSS-5-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="SSS-5" id="SSS-5[]" value="SSS-WIN-CERT-FCTK.docx">
                                            <label for="SSS-5">Windows CERT-FCTK</label>
                                        </li>                                   
                                        <li id="SSS-2-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="SSS-2" id="SSS-2[]" value="SSS-LINUX.docx">
                                            <label for="SSS-2">Linux</label>
                                        </li>   
                                        <li id="SSS-4-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="SSS-4" id="SSS-4[]" value="SSS-LINUX-CERT-FCB.docx">
                                            <label for="SSS-4">Linux CERT-FCB</label>
                                        </li>   
                                        <li id="SSS-6-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="SSS-6" id="SSS-6[]" value="SSS-LINUX-CERT-FCTK.docx">
                                            <label for="SSS-6">Linux CERT-FCTK</label>
                                        </li>                                   
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <br></br>
                                <li>    <!-- MSS -->
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="MSS" id="MSS-0[]" value="MSS-TXT.docx">
                                    <label for="MSS">MSS :</label>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="MSS-1-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="MSS-1" id="MSS-1[]" value="MSS-LINUX.docx">
                                            <label for="MSS-1">Unix Mail Server </label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="MSS-5-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="MSS-5" id="MSS-5[]" value="MSS-LINUX-CERT-FCB.docx">
                                            <label for="MSS-5">Unix Mail Server CERT-FCB</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="MSS-6-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="MSS-6" id="MSS-6[]" value="MSS-LINUX-CERT-FCTK.docx">
                                            <label for="MSS-6">Unix Mail Server CERT-FCTK</label>
                                        </li>                                   
                                        <li id="MSS-2-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="MSS-2" id="MSS-2[]" value="MSS-EXCH.docx">
                                            <label for="MSS-2">MS Exchange</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="MSS-7-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="MSS-7" id="MSS-7[]" value="MSS-EXCH-CERT-FCB.docx">
                                            <label for="MSS-7">MS Exchange CERT-FCB</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="MSS-8-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="MSS-8" id="MSS-8[]" value="MSS-EXCH-CERT-FCTK.docx">
                                            <label for="MSS-8">MS Exchange CERT-FCTK</label>
                                        </li>                                   
                                        <li id="MSS-3-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="MSS-3" id="MSS-3[]" value="MSS-LOUTS.docx">
                                            <label for="MSS-3">Lotus</label>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li id="MSS-3-1-tree">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="MSS-3-1" id="MSS-3-1[]" value="MSS-LOUTS-WIN.docx">
                                                    <label for="MSS-3-1">Lotus For Windows</label>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li id="MSS-3-2-tree">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="MSS-3-2" id="MSS-3-2[]" value="MSS-LOUTS-LINUX.docx">
                                                    <label for="MSS-3-2">Lotus For Linux</label>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="MSS-4-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="MSS-4" id="MSS-4[]" value="MSS-KERIO-TEXT.docx">
                                            <label for="MSS-4">Kerio</label>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li id="MSS-4-1-tree">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="MSS-4-1" id="MSS-4-1[]" value="MSS-KERIO-WIN.docx">
                                                    <label for="MSS-4-1">Kerio For Windows</label>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li id="MSS-4-2-tree">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="MSS-4-2" id="MSS-4-2[]" value="MSS-KERIO-LINUX.docx">
                                                    <label for="MSS-4-2">Kerio For Linux</label>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <br></br>
                                <li>    <!-- GSS -->
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="GSS" id="GSS-0[]" value="GSS-TEXT.docx">
                                    <label for="GSS">GSS :</label>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="GSS-1-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="GSS-1" id="GSS-1[]" value="GSS-Kerio-Winroute.docx">
                                            <label for="GSS-1">Kerio Winroute</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="GSS-2-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="GSS-2" id="GSS-2[]" value="GSS-UNIX.docx">
                                            <label for="GSS-2">Unix gateways</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="GSS-6-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="GSS-6" id="GSS-6[]" value="GSS-UNIX-CERT-FCB.docx">
                                            <label for="GSS-6">Unix gateways CERT-FCB</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="GSS-7-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="GSS-7" id="GSS-7[]" value="GSS-UNIX-CERT-FCTK.docx">
                                            <label for="GSS-7">Unix gateways CERT-FCTK</label>
                                        </li>                                   
                                        <li id="GSS-3-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="GSS-3" id="GSS-3[]" value="GSS-Qbik.docx">
                                            <label for="GSS-3">Qbik</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="GSS-4-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="GSS-4" id="GSS-4[]" value="GSS-MIME.docx">
                                            <label for="GSS-4">MIMEsweeper</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="GSS-5-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="GSS-5" id="GSS-5[]" value="GSS-ISATMG.docx">
                                            <label for="GSS-5">MS ISA Server & Forefront TMG</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="GSS-8-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="GSS-8" id="GSS-8[]" value="GSS-ISATMG-CERT-FCB.docx">
                                            <label for="GSS-8">MS ISA Server & Forefront TMG CERT-FCB</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="GSS-9-tree">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="GSS-9" id="GSS-9[]" value="GSS-ISATMG-CERT-FCTK..docx">
                                            <label for="GSS-5">MS ISA Server & Forefront TMG CERT-FCTK</label>
                                        </li>                                   
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <!-- Button (Double) -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="generate">Confirm Slection</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <button id="generate" name="generate" class="btn btn-primary">Generate File</button>
                        <button id="clearselection" name="clearselection" class="btn btn-inverse" type="reset">Reset Selection</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <!-- Tree Code -->
        <script>
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e) {

                var checked = $(this).prop("checked"),
                    container = $(this).parent(),
                    siblings = container.siblings();

                container.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
                    indeterminate: false,
                    checked: checked
                });

                function checkSiblings(el) {

                    var parent = el.parent().parent(),
                        all = true;

                    el.siblings().each(function() {
                        return all = ($(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked") === checked);
                    });

                    if (all && checked) {

                        parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
                            indeterminate: false,
                            checked: checked
                        });

                        checkSiblings(parent);

                    } else if (all && !checked) {

                        parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", checked);
                        parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("indeterminate", (parent.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0));
                        checkSiblings(parent);

                    } else {

                        el.parents("li").children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
                            indeterminate: true,
                            checked: true
                        });

                    }

                }

                checkSiblings(container);
            });
        </script>

        <!-- Certified Button FULL CERT -->
        <script>
            function checkcert() {
                var el = document.getElementById("type-0");
                if (el.checked) {
                    $('#DSS-4-tree').show();
                    $("#DSS-3-tree").show();
                    $("#DSS-5-tree").show();
                    $("#DSS-6-tree").show();
                    $("#SSS-3-tree").show();
                    $("#SSS-5-tree").show();
                    $("#SSS-4-tree").show();
                    $("#SSS-6-tree").show();
                    $("#MSS-5-tree").show();
                    $("#MSS-6-tree").show();
                    $("#SSS-7-tree").show();
                    $("#MSS-8-tree").show();
                    $("#GSS-6-tree").show();
                    $("#GSS-7-tree").show();
                    $("#GSS-8-tree").show();
                    $("#GSS-9-tree").show();
                    }
                    else {
                    $("#DSS-4-tree").hide();
                    $("#DSS-3-tree").hide();
                    $("#DSS-5-tree").hide();
                    $("#DSS-6-tree").hide();
                    $("#SSS-3-tree").hide();
                    $("#SSS-5-tree").hide();
                    $("#SSS-4-tree").hide();
                    $("#SSS-6-tree").hide();
                    $("#MSS-5-tree").hide();
                    $("#MSS-6-tree").hide();
                    $("#SSS-7-tree").hide();
                    $("#MSS-8-tree").hide();
                    $("#GSS-6-tree").hide();
                    $("#GSS-7-tree").hide();
                    $("#GSS-8-tree").hide();
                    $("#GSS-9-tree").hide();
                    }
           } 
        </script>

        <!-- Certified Button CERT FCB -->  
        <script>
            function checkcertFCB() {
                var el = document.getElementById("type-3");
                if (el.checked) {
                    $('#DSS-3-tree').show();
            }

            }
        </script>
        <!-- Certified Button CERT FCTK --> 
        <script>
            function checkcertFCTK() {
                var el = document.getElementById("type-4");
                if (el.checked) {
                $('#DSS-4-tree').show();

                }
            }
        </script>
        <!-- Non Certified Button -->
        <script>
            function checkcertNON() {
                var el = document.getElementById("type-1");
                if (el.checked) {
                    $('#MSS-3-tree').show();

                }
            }
        </script>
        <!-- Universal Radio Button Selection -->
        <script>
            function checkcertUNI() {
                var el = document.getElementById("type-2");
                if (el.checked)
                    $('#').show();
                else
                    $('#').hide();
            }
        </script>
        <!-- No Space Allowed in Input Text --> 
        <script>
        $("input#filename").on({
              keydown: function(e) {
                if (e.which === 32)
                  return false;
              },
              change: function() {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
              }
            });
        </script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was a very big code to look at. it will take a long time if i go through what you have done. so i am gonna give you a idea how you can achieve what you want. for the following form

```
<form >
<label><input type="radio" name="aa" value="cert" />fcb FCTK</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="aa" value="certFCB" />fcb</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="aa" value="certFCTK" />FCTK</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="aa" value="non" />none</label>
<br />
<br />

<label class="all fcb"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" class="all fcb" />fcb 1</label><br />
<label class="all FCTK"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" />FCTK 1</label><br />
<label class="all fcb"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" />fcb 2</label><br />
<label class="all FCTK"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" />FCTK 2</label><br />
<label class="all fcb"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" />fcb 3</label><br />
<label class="all FCTK"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" />FCTK 3</label><br />
<label class="all fcb"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" />fcb 4</label><br />
</form>
```

JS

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(e) {
            $(".all").hide();
      var a = $(this).val();
      switch(a) {
        case 'cert':
          $(".fcb").show();
          $(".FCTK").show();
          break;
        case 'certFCB':
            $(".fcb").show();
          break;
        case 'certFCTK':
          $(".FCTK").show();
          break;
        case 'non':
        default: 
            $(".all").hide();         
      }
 })
```

CSS

```
.all{
  display:none;
}
```

this kind of solution you are looking for.
working jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/vL423ncp/

Comment: Thanks a lot, code did exactly what you said, BUT it doesn't hide the checkbox it self from the tree, it only hide the text for the checkbox , is there any possible way to hid the box it self at all??   have a look your self  https://jsfiddle.net/w3xw3o3f/

Comment: i added the class not only to the label but to the Li tag it self and looks like its working :) thanks alot , i would have give you reputation up but i need 2 point to do it :)  thanks again

Comment: It Hide the checkbox correct, but the value are still loaded to the child tree :( any idea?

Comment: put both checkbox and value within a container( like i have used label) and show or hide the container.

Comment: Fixed :) thanks a lot, now i'm working on the next step in this project :) from the POST form i need to receive a URL to download a file :) 
Fun Project hahaha , first time ever for me to work with HTML and PHP